# Force FFMPEG to use TCP protocol when reading a RTSP Stream

Tags: tcp, ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm running `ffmpeg` (Windows 7, 64bit) from command line to get a frame from a RTSP stream (second channel from my DVR):

```
ffmpeg  -i "rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/user=xxxx&password=xxxx&channel=2&stream=0.sdp" -rtsp_transport tcp -y video.jpg
```

After running, it waits for about 10 seconds and then i get:

```
[rtsp @ 026fd840] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP
```

After another long wait (2 minutes or so), i get:

```
[rtsp @ 028dd840] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264): unspecified size
```

I read somewhere that I have to force using TCP, because changing from UDP to TCP will not work.

I don't understand why `-rtsp_transport tcp` is not working.

I'm using `ffmpeg version N-62509-g97751e1 built on Apr 17 2014 22:01:31 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)`.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Try this:

    ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -framedrop -strict experimental -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://ip_address:port

Answer (score 47):

Just put the `-rtsp_transport tcp` right after `ffmpeg` to apply it on the input stream. Like this:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://x.x.x.x:554/user=x&password=x&channel=2&stream=0.sdp" -y video.jpg
```

Comment: Why do you have `-rtsp_transport tcp` twice?

Comment: @Notinlist just forgot to remove it from the original answer :) Edited!

Comment: The " _right after `ffmpeg`_ " part is important. It didn't work for me otherwise.

Comment: When I try this I get "Option rtps_transport not found". I know this is an old one, but any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: @DaveSims looks like a typo: `rtsp` not `rtps`