# RTSP Frame Grabbing creates smeared , pixeled and corrupted images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-capture, video-processing, rtsp

I am trying to capture a single frame per second from a RTSP stream with following command
ffmpeg -i rtsp://XXX -q:v 1 -vf fps=fps=1 -strftime 1 ZZZZ\%H_%M_%S.jpg

But some of the frames are smeared ,pixeled and corrupted  - this effect is drastically increases if rtsp resolution is increased [image: Example 1] [image: Example 2](if the resolution is decreased for example to 720P most of the frames are OK)

I have to say that playing same rtsp stream in VLC or FFPLAY is flowless.

How I can fix it to grab better quality

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for that apparently is to force FFMPEG use **TCP PROTOCOL** following way

> ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://XXX -q:v 1 -vf fps=fps=1 -strftime 1 ZZZZ\%H_%M_%S.jpg

thanks a lot to [this question and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238295/force-ffmpeg-to-use-tcp-protocol-when-reading-a-rtsp-stream)