# Using ffmpeg to capture image with low CPU usage from RTSP stream

Tags: ffmpeg, cpu-usage, rtsp

I am using the ffmpeg to capture the image from a RTSP stream in a restricted environment (small memory, disk, and CPU). I am getting a lot of corrupted images and I got the errors from ffmpeg logs as below:

```
[rtsp @ 0x7f164aca1220] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f164aca1220] RTP: missed 21 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f164e7b31a0] error while decoding MB 118 17, bytestream -15
[h264 @ 0x7f164e7b31a0] concealing 6051 DC, 6051 AC, 6051 MV errors in P frame
[rtsp @ 0x7f164aca1220] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f164aca1220] RTP: missed 155 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f164e7b31a0] error while decoding MB 61 19, bytestream -9
[h264 @ 0x7f164e7b31a0] concealing 5868 DC, 5868 AC, 5868 MV errors in P frame
[rtsp @ 0x7f164aca1220] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f164aca1220] RTP: missed 5 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f164e7b31a0] error while decoding MB 68 45, bytestream -5
[h264 @ 0x7f164e7b31a0] concealing 2741 DC, 2741 AC, 2741 MV errors in P frame
[rtsp @ 0x7f164aca1220] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f164aca1220] RTP: missed 4 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f164e7b31a0] error while decoding MB 40 48, bytestream -9
[h264 @ 0x7f164e7b31a0] concealing 2409 DC, 2409 AC, 2409 MV errors in P frame
[rtsp @ 0x7f164aca1220] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f164aca1220] RTP: missed 243 packets
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://******:
version=1.0&action=getRTSPStream&ChannelID=1&ChannelName=Channel1
      Duration: N/A, start: 2.393333, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 15 fps, 20 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Output #0, image2, to 'frames/image6.jpg':
      Metadata:
        title           : Media Presentation
        comment         : StreamingSetting?version=1.0&action=getRTSPStream&ChannelID=1&ChannelName=Channel1
        encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
        Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbn, 20 tbc
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 mjpeg
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
```

I tried several different ways to solve these errors, for example using TCP protocal like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868802/rtsp-frame-grabbing-creates-smeared-pixeled-and-corrupted-images) said:

```
"ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -rtsp_transport tcp -y -i rtsp://****** -vframes 1 frames/image" + str(count)  +".jpg"
```

But it does not work.

I checked the CPU usage while ffmpeg is taking the images and I saw 99% high CPU usage. And I think it is highly possible that the corrupted images are caused by high CPU usage.
I read several posts to solve the ffmpeg high CPU issue while capture the videos not images, such as [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365163/how-to-minimize-usage-of-cpu-memory-by-ffmpeg-when-recording-video),

But do we have any command options to reduce the CPU usage while using the ffmpeg to capture the images from RTSP stream?

Thank you in adance!

Comment: What is the CPU? If it is an Intel with Quick Sync support maybe you can use the hardware H.264 decoder to lower the CPU usage?

Comment: Thanks. We are using Intel Atom Dual-Core Rangeley CPU and I don't think it has Quick Sync support module.